# When I run the code it doesn't present what I expected

Tags: java, netbeans

I tried to Call the Constructor in main Method but I keep on getting Errors,
I don't know why I'm having this problem, if didn't call the Constructor the program will run but doesnt show anything and when I try to call it new EmailLists(); it also make an error which requires String , I tried adding String inside but still wouldnt work,

```
  private BufferedReader br;
  private Connection conn;
  private Statement stmt;
  private String emailadd;
  private String accname;
  private Random rc;
  private String[] acc_name = {"John michael","Christopher Binlayan","Lancelot Binlayan","Jerry Damoyan","Jonathan Kedawen"};
  private Integer numlength = acc_name.length;
  private Integer useracc;


public EmailLists(String username,String Password)throws Exception
{
  username = "root";
  Password = "root";
  Class.forName(Driver1);
  Class.forName(Driver2);
  conn =DriverManager.getConnection(URL,username,Password);
  stmt = conn.createStatement();
  br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  rc = new Random();

  start();

    }
    public void start()throws Exception
    {
        useracc = rc.nextInt(numlength);
        System.out.println("Enter Email Address to be notified:");
        emailadd=br.readLine();

          String insertinto =("Insert Into EMAIL_LIST(EMAIL ADDRESS) VALUES ('"+emailadd+"')");
          stmt.executeUpdate(insertinto);
          System.out.println("Succesfully Added!! Welcome Username: "+acc_name[useracc]+"");

    }


public static void main(String[] args){
   new EmailLists(String username,String password);



}
```

}

Comment: well, the idea is to provide concrete values for fields when you use methods and constructors. Now, look again at your line `new EmailLists(String username,String password);` - do you think this is correct? Or would it make more sense to use proper values for username and password?

Answer (score 0):

You have written

```
DriverManager.getConnection(URL,username,Password)
```

and it compiles fine. note all you did was pass the argument you wanted. I suggest you do the same with the constructor

```
new EmailLists(username, password);
```

i.e. just repeat what has worked already.

BTW These variables need to be set to something before they can be used, or you can just give them values.

```
new EmailLists("myusername", "mypassword");
```

NOTE Since you define these values in the constructor, you don't need to pass them.

```
public EmailLists() throws Exception
{
  String username = "root";
  String password = "root";
```

and then call

```
new EmailLists();
```

Comment: it says cannot find symbol

Comment: @CarlFortuneEslava you have to use proper String values, e.g. `new EmailLists("carl", "mypassword");`. OR define the variables `username` and `password` before. Come on, read again the code, this can't be that difficult to recognize. And declaring the variables inside the constructor doesn't help indeed. The values are not known inside the static method `main` nor do they exist

Comment: Thanks it works!!! love you so much, no homo just happy coding heheh :)